# Implicit conversion error in C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get this error when running my application:

```
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The code:

```
public object BirthDate
{
    get { return date_ofbirth; }
    set { date_ofbirth = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the variable `date_ofbirth` is defined as `DateTime` and the property wrapper `BirthDate` is marked as return/accept `object`.

Change:

```
public object BirthDate 
{ 
    get { return date_ofbirth; } 
    set { date_ofbirth = value; } 
}
```

to

```
public DateTime BirthDate 
{ 
    get { return date_ofbirth; } 
    set { date_ofbirth = value; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the code you've given what your doing with `BirthDate` but from the exception given it looks like you need it to be a `DateTime` object. E.g...

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get {} set {} }
```

If this isn't what you want let us know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you are either going to have to change the property BirthDate to be a System.DateTime or cast:

```
 DateTime myDate  = (DateTime)BirthDate;
```